# Defragment the Windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, defragment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth cleaning the registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry)

Are there benefits to defragmenting the Windows registry? Or at least rewrite it in some way so as to take less space? Is there a reliable and safe tool to do this?

Comment: I'm going to close thise as a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry However, if anyone thinks defragmenting is different from cleaning, please comment

Comment: I believe defragmenting to be reorganisation of the registry file so as to get rid of empty space. Cleaning a registry merely removes entries leaving empty space behind IMHO.

http://maketecheasier.com/why-you-should-defragment-your-registry/2008/01/29

"For instance, after you clean up the registry using the registry scanner tool, all the invalid keys removed leave behind their empty place holders. In the same way, empty keys may get left behind when you uninstall applications from your PC."

I have a feeling these are different. Some way to rewrite the registry should have some gains.