# Is it true that the registry can slow a computer down?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth cleaning the registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry)

Well, is it true that the registry can slow a computer down? And how do I fix it? I've seen too many suspicious registry fixing tools.

The computer is a Windows 7 x64 machine