# Not able to install SEP in XP

Tags: windows-xp, symantec

Whenever I attempted an install setup is automatically closed in task manager. I think some error occurs in registry but I don't have any registry cleaner. Please advise me of a free registry cleaner

Comment: And.... what is SEP?

Comment: Are you refering to Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Comment: The simple solution is to reinstall Windows XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows registry and system cleaner applications?](http://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications)

Comment: See [Is it worth cleaning the registry?](http://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry)

Comment: Also, not a real question; it's [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

If SEP is in fact Symantec Endpoint Protection, there is a possible issue that can cause this.

[SEP Tech Support](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95608) has a number of references.  This is one that I had on hand:

- Open Regedit
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
- On the right hand side, delete the value `PendingFileRenameOperations`
- Run the install without rebooting the PC

In some cases you may need to copy the installer locally if trying to install from a network location.  Not always an issue but seemed to be in some cases.