# What happens when I uninstall Modern UI Applications?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, modern-ui

What exactly happens when I uninstall Modern UI Applications from within the Tile View (not the *Programs and Features* from desktop view)?

Will **ALL** the registry keys be removed? Will all the settings files be removed? Will the files just be put into the trash?

Or trying thousands of apps from the Windows Store will finally lead to a cluttered registry?

Comment: "Registry rot" does not exist. http://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry

Comment: Instead of closing the question because answerers/commenters **took out one element which produces debates** you should have focussed on the main title of the question: *What happens after uninstalling*. I propose a reopening, sadly I don't know how or am not eligible.

Comment: Reopened based on @klyonrad's comment. There must be an objective answer to this given enough knowledge of the Windows internals. By the way, klyonrad, you can flag a question for attention to have it reopened or post a request on [meta].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps are installed to a separate sandbox for each app - uninstallation destroys these sandboxes as if they never existed. As for the registry, Apps do not appear to have any direct access to the registry, so there's no issue there (and to be honest, a few stray keys will not affect performance noticeably - anyone that tries to convince you otherwise is probably going to try and sell you a pointless tool.)

If you reinstall an app, it will go through the exact same experience as if it were the first time it was installed on the device. There is a small caveat to those applications that can roam their data, which I believe will continue to do so to devices with the app installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as registry rot, and trying millions is bound to leave some traces around your PC but not enough to warrant a notable performance impact.

Comment: It would be great to also address the other points of the OP – their actual question of what happens to registry keys and settings files.